# Excel Combining ISNUMBER(SEARCH and another AND and OR condition

Tags: excel, search, nested, excel-formula, formulas

I am able to achieve what I want using 2 formulas but I would like to use only 1.

I am currently using the following formula, to check if a cell contains string1 or string2 to return ST1 or ST2.

> =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("STRING1",C3)),"ST1",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("STRING2",C3)),"ST2",A3))

Then I am using the following formula on the column that contains the previous formula,

> =IF(AND(A3="AE",OR(C3="ST1",C3="ST2")),E3,A3)

Is it possible to combine everything in just one formula?

**The logic should be:**

If cell A1 contains "string0" AND cell C1 contains "string1" return ST1;

If cell A1 contains "string0" AND cell c1 contains "string2" return ST2;

Otherwise return A1

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would solve it

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(SEARCH("string0",A2),0)>0,IFERROR(SEARCH("string1",C2),0)>0), "ST1", IF(AND(IFERROR(SEARCH("string0",A2),0)>0,IFERROR(SEARCH("string2",C2),0)>0), "ST2", A2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help it worked perfectly, however I described wrongly the logic since it MUST be 
IF cell A1 ="string0" AND cell C1 contains "string1" return ST1 
if cell A1="string0" AND cell C1 contains "string2" return ST2. 
otherwise return A1

I have adapted your formual to this one and it worked perfectly, many many thanks again
=IF(AND(B2="string0",IFERROR(SEARCH("Arabic",D2),0)>0), "ST1", IF(AND(B2="string0",IFERROR(SEARCH("English",D2),0)>0), "ST2", A2))